# how to hide the slider when clicking somewhere else in body

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have this contact us button sticking to the left of the screen which has a form attached which is hidden by default(because it has negative left of (-472px)).

Now When I click on it left becomes 0px and form slides in(using animate method) with the contact us button itself.

When I click again on the contact us button form and button slides back and hide having left property set to -472 again.

Now I want it also to hide if use click somewhere else on the screen instead of click just the button. I've tried but now its slides in and slides back and hide at the same time.

How can I make it work properly.

code where the problem is: jquery code which is not working is that the bottom of the code like

```
        // clicking somewhere else  ------------------------------------------------------------------
    jQuery("body").click(function(e){
```

Full code

```
    <style>
    #form_contact_wrapper{position: absolute;top: 225px;left: -472px;z-index: 999;}
    #contact-btn-div{top: 267px;float:left;}
    #form_contact {z-index: 999;width: 450px;border: 1px solid;border-color: #BBB;padding: 10px;background-color: #FFF;float:left;}    
    #form_contact p.required{width: 450px;}    
</style>

<?php if(Mage::helper('customer')->isLoggedIn() && Mage::app()->getStore()->getCode()=="default"):?>

<div id="form_contact_wrapper">

    <div id="form_contact" class="form_contact">

        <div id="form_contact_container" class="form_contact_container">
            <div class="form_contact_div">
                <?php
                $filter = new Mage_Widget_Model_Template_Filter();
                $_widget = $filter->filter('{{widget type="webforms/form" webform_id="' . Mage::getStoreConfig('webforms/contacts/webform') . '" template="webforms/default.phtml" redirect_url="www.google.com" }}');
                echo $_widget;
                ?>
                <a id="contact_new_question_link" href="javascript:void(0)" style="display: none;text-decoration: underline;"><span><span id = "contact_ask_another">Ask another Question</span></span></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="contact-btn-div"><a href="#" id="contact-btn"><img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/contact-us.png'); ?>"></a></div>

</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

    jQuery(function(){
        var webform_id = <?php echo Mage::getStoreConfig('webforms/contacts/webform'); ?> ;
        var webform_label = jQuery("#webform_"+webform_id+"_form form div ul li div label" );
        var webform_fields = jQuery("#webform_"+webform_id+"_form form div ul li div label").next().children();         


        webform_label.css('width', '100px');
        webform_fields.css("width","250px");

        // with sucess text
        if(jQuery('#form_contact_container .webforms-success-text').length == 1){
            jQuery("#form_contact_wrapper").animate({'left': '0px'});
            jQuery("#form_contact_wrapper").addClass('active');
            jQuery('#form_contact_container .webforms-success-text').show();
            jQuery('#form_contact_container .webforms-success-text p').attr('id','success_msg');
            jQuery("a#contact_new_question_link").show();
            jQuery("a#contact_new_question_link").addClass('active');
            jQuery("#webform_"+webform_id+"_form").css({display:'none'});

            jQuery("#contact-btn-div").toggle(function(){
                jQuery("#form_contact_wrapper").removeClass('active');
                jQuery("#form_contact_wrapper").animate({'left': '-472px'});                 

            },function(){
                jQuery("#form_contact_wrapper").animate({'left': '0px'});
                jQuery("#form_contact_wrapper").addClass('active');

            });


            if(jQuery("ul.messages").length > 0){
                //
                jQuery("#feedback_btn_form").after(jQuery("ul.messages"));

            }


        }

        // without success text
        if(jQuery('#form_contact_container .webforms-success-text').length == 0){     

           jQuery("#contact-btn-div").click(function(){
               if(jQuery("#form_contact_wrapper").hasClass('active')){
                    jQuery("#form_contact_wrapper").animate({'left': '-472px'});
                    jQuery("#form_contact_wrapper").removeClass('active');
               }else{
                    jQuery("#form_contact_wrapper").animate({'left': '0px'});
                    jQuery("#form_contact_wrapper").addClass('active');
               }
           });                

        }

        // new question 
        jQuery("a#contact_new_question_link").click(function(){
            // jQuery("#form_contact_wrapper").animate({'left': '-472px'});
            jQuery('#form_contact_container .std.webforms-success-text').css({display:'none'});
            jQuery(this).hide();
            jQuery("#webform_"+webform_id+"_form").show();

        });

        // clicking somewhere else  ------------------------------------------------------------------
        jQuery("body").click(function(e){
            if(jQuery("#form_contact_wrapper").hasClass('active')){
            if(jQuery(e.target).closest('#form_contact').length == 0 && e.target.id != '#contact-btn-div'){                
                jQuery("#form_contact_wrapper").removeClass('active');
                jQuery("#form_contact_wrapper").animate({'left': '-472px'});                   
                }
            }
        });


    });
</script>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Please suggest something. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Use `.blur()` method. The blur event is sent to an element when it loses focus.  An element can lose focus via keyboard commands, such as the Tab key, or by mouse clicks elsewhere on the page. [Read more](http://api.jquery.com/blur/)

Comment: It seems to be the right solution. But I don't know why it's not working. I did console log but it is not even triggering it.